# How to make a QPushButton disabled

Tags: qt

I created lots of [QPushButtons](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qpushbutton.html), added clicked signal and a slot name ´deneme()´ to all of the buttons with `QT DESIGNER` and the thing I want to do is; when I clicked any button, some operation should be done and lastly the button should be disabled but we do not know which button is clicked. I know I can disable the buttons with `setEnabled()` and `isEnabled()` but I do not know how to disable them.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If I understood correctly you connected various `QPushButtons` to the same slot. Inside of the slot `deneme()` you want to know which of the buttons was `clicked`. 
You can do something like:

```
  void deneme() {
    QPushButton * b = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(sender());
    if (b) {
       if (b == button1) { //button1 clicked
           //doSomething();
       } 
       else {
          if (b == button2) {
             //doSomething();
          }
       }
       b->setEnabled(false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think that is correct but it gives error that " `qobject_cast` was not declared in this scope" even if I include `qobject.h`

Answer (score 13):

Why is setEnabled not working then? [The reference](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#enabled-prop).

So a simple setEnabled(false); is enough.

```
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(someParent);
button->setEnabled(false);
```

If the connecting a event handler on the click event of the button maybe you should look at the QT documentation:
[Signal and slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: The problem is I created Gui and added slot all the button with Qt designer. After I click any button some operation will be done and lastly the button should be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You mean Button has to be disabled right after clicking on it? I guess in that case you probably want to do something like this:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget 
{
Q_OBJECT

// ...

private slots:
  void disableButton();

private:
  QPushButton *myButton;

// ...
};

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent = NULL) : QWidget(parent) 
{

///...
myButton = new QPushButton("click me", this);
connect(myButton, SIGNAL(clicked), this, SLOT(disableButton));
// ...
}

void MyWidget::disableButton() 
{
myButton->setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Your answer probably correct but The problem is I created Gui and added slot all the button with Qt designer. After I click any button some operation will be done and lastly the button should be disabled and I am so new at this programming :(

Comment: You mean your problem is that in this method you can't define which Button was pressed? This problem is solvable too. You just should use QSignalMapper. It allows you to map paramless signals (like clicked() signal in QPushButton) to slots that accept one parameter. So you can modify disableButton() method in above code sample to receive parameter indicating which button was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Bruno's answer is correct.

```
sender();
```

returns a `QObject*`
You can cast it to a `QPushButton*`
using either 
C Style cast i.e `QPushButton* clickedButton = (QPushButton*)(sender())`
or
`QPushButton* clickedButton = static_cast<QPushButton*>(sender())`
or
QPushButton * clickedButton = qobject_cast(sender());
as far as i know qobject_cast works similar to dynamic_cast<> in C++. But if you are having compilation problems any solution given above should work fine.